# Iniciar servicio no me funciona mediante Systemctl

Tags: linux, bash, servicio, configuración

**Hola, mencionar antes de nada que soy novatillo y que si tenéis cualquier cosa que creéis que puedo hacer mejor a la hora de redactar la pregunta me lo podéis decir y intentare arreglarlo cuanto antes.**

Primero de todo comentar que los comandos que lanza y que están definidos en él ".service" funcionan si los lanzas manualmente.
A continuación el contenido del fichero:

```
[Unit]
Description=Node Red Express
After=networking.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/pi/node-red-express/script_gestionador.sh start
ExecStatus=/home/pi/node-red-express/script_gestionador.sh status
ExecStop=/home/pi/node-red-express/script_gestionador.sh stop
User=pi
RootDirectory=/
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/node-red-express/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Mas cosas a comentar es que es necesario que se lancen con el usuario "pi", que tenga acceso a todo des de la raíz hacia abajo (siempre que tenga permisos) esto simplemente establece la "jail", y el working directory debe de ser el indicado pues sino algunos comandos de más adentro no irán correctamente...

Los permisos del archivo a ejecutar también están bien puestos para el usuario PI.

```
-rwxrwxr--   1 pi pi     4412 may 20 16:07 script_gestionador.sh
```

Y para que el usuario sin privilegios de PI puede ejecutar systemctl he usado sudoers sin contraseña para systemctl en concreto, justo debajo la línea...

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown, /bin/systemctl
```

Tal y como he dicho antes si ejecuto los comandos manualmente des de la terminal funcionan, pero si ejecuto un **sudo systemctl start node.service**, es raro porque no parece que realice ninguna acción ni nada... Extrañado realice un **journalctl -xe** y esto es lo que me sale...

```
    may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi sudo[871]:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start node.service
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi sudo[871]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Node Red Express...
-- Subject: Unit node.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit node.service has begun starting up.
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[877]: /home/pi/node-red-express
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[877]: Proceso iniciado con pid... 880
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[877]: Proceso Monitorizacion iniciado con exito con PID... 881
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[882]: /home/pi/node-red-express
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[882]: Aviso: Se trataran de parar AMIGABLEMENTE asi que puede tardar unos cuantos segundos,
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[882]: en caso de que tarde demasiado y no se pare mediante este script se debera borrar tambien el
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[882]: el archivo /home/pi/node-red-express/pid.txt y /home/pi/node-red-express/pid_m.txt
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[882]: donde se guarda los pid de cada proceso
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[882]: Se va a terminar el proceso con PID... 880
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[882]: Se va a terminar el proceso de monitoraje con PID... 881
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[882]:
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[882]: Proceso terminado con exito
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[877]: Signal 15 (TERM) caught by ps (3.3.12).
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi script_gestionador.sh[877]: ps:ps/display.c:66: please report this bug
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Node Red Express.
-- Subject: Unit node.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit node.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
may 20 16:51:58 raspberrypi sudo[871]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
lines 1686-1723/1723 (END)
```

La verdad es que es bastante curioso porque según veo en esto último es como si el los comandos de start y stop se ejecutasen uno después del otro... Cuando, insisto, el script que recibe los parámetros si lo ejecuto tal cual sale en el archivo de configuración **".service"** funcionan a la perfección...

Por no hablar de la linia de **"ps:ps/display.c:66: please report this bug"**

**Voy a seros sincero... No sé por dónde empezar a coger este problema...
¿A alguien se le ocurre algo?**
Gracias de Antemano

Comment: Con qué distribución y kernel trabajas?

Answer (score 0):

humm no se si te servirá.
yo al final opte por una solución mas sencilla.
(aunque menos robusta que un servicio).

he añadido esta linea al final de /etc/rc.local

```
(cd /home/pi/ ;su  pi -c "nohup node-red --max-old-space-size=196&")&
```

cada vez que se inicia la maquina se carga el node en segundo plano.
Ademas le limita la memoria que puede consumir.
Lo tengo corriendo en una Pi1 desde hace ya unos años.